# How to use cookie that maintains session in Android client?

Tags: android, session-cookies

Documentation reads about class Cookie: "Cookie, HTTP "magic-cookie" represents a piece of state information that the HTTP agent and the target server can exchange to maintain a session." But how to use this magic? Anybody can tell? Specifically, I want to use cookie to maintain session on the browser side. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code for maintain cookies its work fine for me :-

```
            CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();

            // Create local HTTP context
            HttpClientContext localContext = HttpClientContext.create();
            // Bind custom cookie store to the local context
            localContext.setCookieStore(cookieStore);

            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://localhost/");
            System.out.println("Executing request " + httpget.getRequestLine());

            // Pass local context as a parameter
            CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
            try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                List<Cookie> cookies = cookieStore.getCookies();
                for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println("Local cookie: " + cookies.get(i));
                }
                EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
            } finally {
                response.close();
            }
```

Comment: I am sorry but there is no such class as HttpClientContext.

Answer (score 0):

After getting your response from your request from Http, just add below code:

```
public static List<Cookie> cookies;
try {
        cookies = httpclient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        sync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }

//Sync Method:

    public void sync() {
            if (cookies != null) {

                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
                cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
                for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {

                    Cookie sessionInfo = cookie;
                    String cookieString = sessionInfo.getName() + "=" + sessionInfo.getValue() + "; domain=" + sessionInfo.getDomain();
                    cookieManager.setCookie(YOUR DOMAIN, cookieString);
                    CookieSyncManager.getInstance().sync();
                }
            }
        }
```